# Problem with animating values ​in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have a problem with a number transition animation.

I wanted the animation to always continue from the last number generated, but it is always repeating the first value transition made

I already looked for someone who had a similar problem, but I didn't find

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  Animation numberTransitionAnimation;
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  animationController = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
  numberTransitionAnimation = IntTween(begin: currentNumber, end: newNumber).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.linear));
  }

  int selectedNumber;
  int currentNumber = 0;
  int newNumber = 0;
  int total = 2000;


  void selectNumber(selectedNumber){
    
    newNumber = selectedNumber + currentNumber;
    
    currentNumber = newNumber;
    
    animationController.reset();
    animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child){
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(numberTransitionAnimation.value.toString() + " / $total"),
                  // \/ Test to see if the method is working
                  Text(currentNumber.toString()),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () => selectNumber(100), child: Text('100')),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: ()=> selectNumber(200), child: Text('200')),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: ()=> selectNumber(300), child: Text('300')),
                ],
              )
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

I ask you to ignore the organization of the codes, I end up disorganizing by changing the code looking for a solution

I am grateful if anyone can help me

Comment: Can you check by using `reverse` in `selectNumber` method instead of `forward`?

Comment: I tried to use reverse and the animation did not occur.

Animation only happens if I directly put numbers in `begin` and `end` or non-zero initial values ​​for the `selectedNumber` and `newNumber` variables

Comment: Okay, use `setState(){}` at the end in the `selectNumber`

Comment: I've already tried with and without `setState () {}`, but I tried to do it again with your indication and it didn't happen.

I even thought it was related to the values ​​of the variables at the time of the animation initialization, in which `currentNumber` and `newNumber` could always have equal values. But by placing a symbolic value of 0 for `currentNumber` and 200 for `newNumber`, the animation occurs, but it always repeats the animation of these values, even though the variables already store different values.

Comment: You could try `ac.forward(from: currentNumber)`

Comment: I also made this attempt before, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: I also asked this question on StackOverflow in Portuguese and they helped me with that. I didn't return here because I was afraid to answer my own question with the answer from another post and maybe violate some rule, but I decided to paste the link to help those in need https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/470028/problema-com-anima%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-valores-no-flutter